# How are joists secured to sill?

Tags: framing, joists, construction, sill

From what I’ve read on residential construction, the process of building the first floor goes like this:

1. Foundation of some kind is set
2. Sill plates are bolted to the foundation
3. Floor joists are set to bear on the sill plates and are nailed to rim joists

I haven’t seen any information on how the floor or rim joists are subsequently attached to the sill plates.

Is friction and weight expected to keep them in place?

If so, why do the sill plates need to be bolted down?

Comment: You nail the rim joist to the sill plate every 16in or so. Watch this video (starting here for this specific question https://youtu.be/yh6cMQnWGwA?t=1090 but the whole thing, and the whole series at large, is worth watching if you're building a home or getting into construction).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The floor joists are secured to the sill joists by installing wall sheathing (plywood or OSB board) that laps from the sill plate up the wall to the double top plate. When the sheathing is nailed to the sill plates, rim joists, studs and double top plate, then all the components are secured in place.

The thickness and size and spacing of the nails in each component are determined by the load (we call this load: “shear”) they need to resist. If the walls are extra tall, or have many windows, then extra thick and special increased nailing may be required.

Likewise, if the building is located in a seismic zone or high wind area, then additional nailing AND special steel holddowns may be required at certain locations to resist the shear loads and keep the floor joists aligned with the sill, studs, and double top plate.

The sill transfers the shear loads to the concrete foundation. The size and spacing of the anchor bolts is determined by the shear load that is transferred through the walls to the foundation.

Comment: Floor joists are secured to the sill plate through the rim joist, not through exterior sheathing. You nail the floor joists to the rim joist after nailing the rim joist to the sill plate. Wall sheathing only adds rigidity to the walls for shear. Sheathing will not do anything substantial to help attach the rim joist to the sill plate... big yikes if that's the only thing attaching the house to the foundation.

Comment: @TylerH So you think the toe-nailing is what keeps the house on the foundation during a seismic event or high wind event or even a flood event? Those toe-nails are for keeping the rim joists in line until the sheathing can be installed.

Comment: The toenailing with 16 penny nails attaching two primary members together will do a hell of a lot more than some 8 penny nails attaching one primary member to a quaternary member (walls attached to floor plate, attached to rim joist thru subfloor planks/sheathing). Ideally, you have *both* toenailed 16 penny nails attaching the sill to the rim and then 8 penny (or whatever) nails attaching the sheathing to the sill plate. I have never heard of any build philosophy that did not call for attaching the rim joist to the sill plate directly.

Comment: I don't want to go so far as to say it's unsafe construction, but if you are not attaching the floor framing to the sill plate directly, either at the rim joists or at the end of each inner floor joists, you will get smacked in the back of the head in the Southeast. Maybe it really is different in other regions... I will grant you that possibility. But googling doesn't seem to give any results other than "yes, attach the rim joist to the sill plate directly", either.

Comment: @TylerH I think we both agree that having both toe-nailing and face-nailing through sheathing is best. I never said don’t toe-nail. In fact it would be difficult to keep the rim joists in place until the sheathing is installed, especially when run parallel to the joists. However, when a horizontal force acts on a building, that force will “unzip” those toe-nails in a second. I can guarantee you that nails in shear withstand far more resistance than toe-nails.  In fact, the code gives values for various thicknesses of sheathing and various nails at various spacing (including blocked and

Comment: @TylerH (including blocked and unblocked edges). Please show me the value of toe-nailing two boards together. I think you’ll find it’s customary to do so, but there’s no shear value established anywhere in the code for toe-nailing.